# The branch prediction answer is overflowing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A few days ago, [Mysticial's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) to [the famous branch prediction question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) passed 10000 votes. This is, as far as I know, the only question or answer with a 5-digit score anywhere on the SE network.

When you find this answer in search results (e.g. search [score:4600](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A4600) on SO; see image below), the vote count overflows the `.stats` box, at least on Windows 7 with Chrome 31:

[image: "10105 votes" overflowing stats box in search results]

This is a thing that should probably not happen.

(Note that there are no issues with 4-digit-score questions or answers.)

---

**Update (21 Jan 2015):** the new design on Stack Overflow fixes this bug:

[image: no more overflow]

No other site has any posts with a score remotely close to 10000 (the closest is [this one on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/46760/80891)), and in any case, I don't think any other site with super-high-scoring posts uses a colored `.stats` box. Looks like the overflow has been slain!

But just you wait until the branch prediction answer gets to a score of 100000...

[image: the return of the overflow]

Comment: This is probably the first bug of its kind that I have seen that was not caused by Jon Skeet

Comment: Maybe it should just say 10K

Comment: I'd vote for 10.1K.

Comment: @LanceRoberts does that fit?

Comment: Well, 4 numbers fit fine, I'd think a dot added in there would work, but I'd expect them to test it out.

Comment: Ah, now it shows up on meta... I remember the moment it hit 10k, a couple of us from the Anime chatroom went around searching for all the overflow bugs that it would cause. In the end we found only two: 1) Search. 2) The answers tab on my user profile. Right now, the 10107 only looks a bit off-center in my answers tab. But back when it was 10000, the last digit was partially cut off. It doesn't happen now since the font is not fixed-width and the "1" in the middle is shorter.

Comment: Approximately one hundred thousand people don't know how voting works.

Comment: @Mysticial How does it feel to write an answer so good, *other* people get silver badges off of it?

Comment: Related Answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14686/13295

Comment: @TheGrinch I'm probably just slow, but I don't get what you mean by that. There are only ten thousand votes on that answer, and about twenty thousand votes in the screenshot (by score, I haven't looked at the up/down). Who are the hundred thousand voters you speak of?

Comment: @jadarnel27 - must be all the SO members who *didn't* upvote this question, may god have mercy on their wretched souls

Comment: @jdarnel: Oh, hell.  I got the decimal point in the wrong place.  I meant to say ten thousand.

Comment: @TheGrinch Haha, nice.  I wasted a lot of time and thought because I assumed I was the one missing something =P

Answer (score 12):

This issue (though without this test case) was brought up four years ago in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views) and the powers that be decided to just put the `k` or `m` in the text underneath the votes or views number.

I think that they should change to what [this answer recommends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14686/13295), and put the `k` or `M` as a suffix to the number itself, just like we do with reputation, and just use the word 'votes' or 'views' without the prefix.

Example for this case:

### 10.1k

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution would be to just reduce the font size for vote counts longer than four digits.  In fact, I wrote some client-side JavaScript to do just that:

```
$('.stats .vote-count-post strong').filter( function () {
    return this.textContent.length > 4
} ).css( 'font-size', '80%' );
```

With this fix, the [example search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A4600) given in the question above looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of five-digit vote count with reduced font size]

I've added the JS code above to version 1.4 of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), a collection of client-side CSS and JavaScript fixes packaged as a GreaseMonkey-style user script.  If you're using a compatible browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, possibly Safari and others, but unfortunately not IE or most mobile browsers), please give it a try!